# Is it possible to create an IIS Reverse proxy with built-in credentials?

Tags: reverse-proxy, iis-7, authentication

I've got... a strange customer request.

They have a specific custom site that requires authentication. I cannot make changes to this site.

They are showing a specific page from that site on a web-capable TV as a sort of "status panel". The problem is... they're annoyed they have to type in the login credentials every time the TV is powered on.

As such, I was thinking about creating some kind of reverse-proxy that doesn't use authentication (i.e. anonymous) and then passes on pre-fixed credentials when accessing the target site (if I recall the target site uses Windows auth). I could then set up Windows Firewall rules to only permit the TV access to the proxy (to keep things fairly secure).

Is such a thing possible in IIS? I know a reverse-proxy can be set up in IIS using Url Rewrite and Application Based Routing, but I'm not sure about the credentials bit (which, in the end, is the most important).

Comment: I'm not sure about passing pre-saved windows credentials through to the app but if client certificate authentication is available on the app you could possibly load a client cert on the TV.

Comment: @duct_tape_coder Honestly, no clue; as stated, the app itself is a bit of a black-box as far as I'm concerned.